# Email does not exist error ( mail created from cpanel )

Tags: cpanel, webmail

I have created a new email address from cpanel of my domain, I am able to connect webmail, and send mail to my gmail account, but when I try replay message or send a new message to my domain email address, I get Delivery Status Notification (Failure) error. I have whm and cpanel but don't have ssh, Thank you

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

     r@m***.com

Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain m***.com by aspmx.l.google.com..

The error that the other server returned was:
550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try
550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or
550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at
550 5.1.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=6596 cji10287580lad.113 - gsmtp

----- Message suppressed ----
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Your domain isn't well configured for email. If the email server your domain is pointing to isn't itself or if your hosting doesn't support email, cpanel won't fully work. You will only be able to send email, but not receive it.

You can check what server is handling email on your domain by doing a simple MX Lookup: http://mxtoolbox.com/

The problem in my case was that my client was using 'Google Apps' as email service provider, therefore emails I created via cpanel wouldn't fully work (couldn't receive email) because Google can't find the emails I create through cpanel.

What you can do now is either create an email with the email server that is handling your domain or change the domain's MX records back to you so you can use cpanel emails.